# Is it possible to limit how much CPU power a process can take?

Tags: cpu, cpulimit

I'm wondering, is there way to tell a process how much processor power it can take?

The problem is I'm converting video with *Arista* (video converter) and I'm annoyed by the fan running like crazy, when I look at the task monitor, it's taking over 92% of CPU.

Can I (somehow) tell it that it can take just 20%?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) tool (also is present in [debian repo](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/cpulimit) and should be in other distros).

It's usage is pretty simple:

```
cpulimit -p PID -l MAX_CPU_LEVEL
```

You can also use process name, or full path to binary. Details you can find on the [man page](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/cpulimit.1/).

Comment: ha-ha :) , works perfectly, thanks +1

Comment: The code at the noted URL has not been updated in quite some time. Another group has picked it up and continued development at http://limitcpu.sf.net/.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is by using the (relatively) new kernel interface called [cgroups](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt) (wikipedia article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)). It allows more fine grained control of how much cpu/memory/io/etc a process/user/group is allowed to consume.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be exactly what you are looking for, you can use the `renice` program to change the program priority to prevent it from slowing down other applications on the system. `renice -n 20 -p [pid]`, where [pid] is replaced with the process ID of Arista would likely lower its' resource usage, and would definitely decrease system slowdown.

Comment: The OP is not complaining about the process slowing down other applications but about the fan running like crazy, `renice` can't do anything against the latter. At best it will slow down the video converter but the competing processes (if any) will maintain the CPU load as before.